# MVC3 RequireHTTPS Simple

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ssl, iis-7.5, requirehttps

Im running an MVC3 app within an IIS7.5 instance on a winsvr2008 R2 box. Now if i set RequireHttps either globally or on each class, my url never gets rewritten at all, in fact it changes nothing? Im using my own custom forms authentication module BTW,which encrypts the forms auth ticket on the client.....would this be preventing the RequireHttps attrib from working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is OK , was due to IIS7.5 not re compiling my source code after making live changes on the server. So was not picking up the recently added global attributes .Doh!